# webdriver / node.js: execution won't wait for element

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

in Internet Explorer 11, I try to use driver.wait() to wait for an element before doing something to it and I get the following error intermittently, for different elements:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at C:\tools\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:909:22
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\tools\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1343:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\tools\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2868:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\tools\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2851:21)
    at C:\tools\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2730:27
    at C:\tools\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
```

This is the code snippet that I call. It is failing on the `return driver.wait(` line.

```
function wait_for_element_and_click(element){

    var target_element;

    return driver.wait(
        function()  {   return driver.isElementPresent(element) }, 
        10000
    )
    .then(function(){   element.click() })
}
```

And this is how I call it.

```
function select_and_click_links(){

    var make_field = "make_field_id";
    var model_field = "model_field_id";

    return driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.id(make_field)))
    .then(function()    { wait_for_and_click_element(webdriver.By.id(model_field)) })   

}
```

Interestingly, I don't it has ever failed at the line just before (which seems to be doing the exact same thing (i.e. `return driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.id(make_field)))`)

Things I have tried:
* replacing `function(){ return driver.isElementPresent(element) }` with `webdriver.until.elementLocated(element)`
* excluding the optional timeout.
* returning the result of the `wait_and_click_element` call (yep, trying pretty much anything here).

Things I haven't tried:
* a different browser (as the application works correctly in IE - so, if this is an IE quirk, it's a dealbreaker for us).

The script still fails intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of locate try to use isDisplayed to ensure that the element is visible on the page. `webdriver.until.elementLocated` might only be checking the element in DOM.